# vimdiff style color question: top & bottom lines

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, highlight, color-scheme, vimdiff

I cannot find what the highlight name (or highlight group) is to change the guifg and guibg colors of the top and bottom lines in vimdiff. (The bottom line *above* the statusline, that is).

(More specifically, the lines with the "+--" at their left edge, to the right of the line number.)

In the attached screenshot, these are line numbers 1 and 18. (They're the lines with the bright silver background and cyan foreground colors.)

I would like to be able to change the colors of those lines in my vimrc.

I've looked through the Vim Reference Manual at everything I could find on highlighting and :highlight groups and have done several searches that have so far yielded no useful info.

Thanks for any insights.

[image: vimdiff screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Folded` is the group responsible for those lines. See `:help hl-Folded`.

In the future, you can use `:so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/hitest.vim` to try to visually find the matching group.

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/vim/colorschemes/wiki/How-to-override-a-colorscheme%3F